# client side validation and server side validation in java script and asp.net respectively?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

hi all i want to know that can we validate a control  which is  out side a form element in asp.net(server side validation)and outside a form element in html(client side validation) let's take a closer look

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text"  name="first name"/>
</body>
</html>
```

can we apply clien side validation on above text box by java script ?

in asp.net

```
<form runat="server">
</form>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

here i have written textbox after the form will it validate at server side ?

Comment: Validating this on server side is a bit of a oddity, as it will not be posted back, as it is not in the form?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure, if you set the input to runat the server and give it an ID:

```
<input type="text"  name="first name" runat="server" id="myserversideid"/>
```

You can then use the [validation controls](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_refvalidationcontrols.asp) as you would normally

Comment: i am talking about 2nd on i means asp.net not on html ?

Comment: acording to you if i write any asp contro out side form then it will not run on server ?

Answer (score 2):

Last time I checked, it wasn't valid HTML to have form elements, such as inputs, outside a form.

In any case, it won't work on the server-side because ASP.NET does not know the textbox exists. I could see it working client-side, but I have never tried this as it makes no sense.

What are you trying to achieve here? There is likely a better solution.

Comment: but sir it's working well in any browser  ? i means when we apply only client side validation then need not necessary to keep it inside form afterall i am not sending data on server side for validation ?